# Function for onMouseDown for file

Tags: reactjs, file, mouseevent, preview, onmousedown

I have input type as file.I am defining onMouseDown function for it.In order,change the position of file preview.I am getting the follwing error:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'left' of undefined

```
 <input 
     type="file"
     className="file"
     id="file-browser-input"
     name="file-browser-input"
     ref ={input=>this.fileInput=input}
     onDragOver={(e)=>{
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     }
    }
     onDrop={this.onFileLoad.bind(this)
     onChange={this.onFileLoad.bind(this)}
     onMouseDown={this.catchItem.bind(this)} 
/>

catchItem(e) {

    this.style.left = e.pageX - this.clientWidth / 2 + "px";
    this.style.top = e.pageY - this.clientHeight / 2 + "px";
    this.onmousemove = function(e) {
    this.style.left = e.pageX - this.clientWidth / 2 + "px";
    this.style.top = e.pageY - this.clientHeight / 2 + "px";
    }
    this.onmouseup = function() {
    this.onmousemove = null; // onmouseup event [ redirect mousemove event signal to null instead of the 
    drag-able element]
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `this.style` is undefined

```
catchItem(e) {
    this.style.left = e.pageX - this.clientWidth / 2 + "px"; // either this one
    this.style.top = e.pageY - this.clientHeight / 2 + "px";
    this.onmousemove = function(e) {
       this.style.left = e.pageX - this.clientWidth / 2 + "px"; // or this one
       this.style.top = e.pageY - this.clientHeight / 2 + "px";
    }
    ...
}
```

Since you don't bind `this.onmousemove`'s context to the class' context, I suspect it to be the second one.

Any reason you're not using arrow functions in this case?

fix:

```
catchItem(e) {

    this.onmousemove = (e) => {
       ...
    }

    or

    this.onmousemove = function(e){
       ...
    }
    this.onmousemove.bind(this);


}
```

Comment: Yeah,it is the second one.

Comment: can you please tell me how do i bind this.onmousemove's context to the class context